# Avoiding excessive ! use in Swift function (cellForRowAtIndexPath)

Tags: swift

Simply put: How can I avoid writing `!` for every line in the Swift code below? I considered `guard`, but the UITableViewCell initialiser *can* return nil, but on the other hand `cellForRowAtIndexPath` *must* return non-nil, which seems like a contradiction in itself. Hope there is a short and sweet way.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier)
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }
    cell!.textLabel?.text = ...
    cell!.textLabel?.textColor = ...
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.textColor = ...
    cell!.detailTextLabel?.textColor = ...
    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Plus one for caring about the quality of your code.

Comment: @PaulCantrell's answer is great, but if you encounter a similar situation in which you can't remove the optionality of a variable, you can use the `if let ` statement, to bind the optional value to a new name (perhaps even the same name) as a non optional, whilst also giving you the ability to handle the `nil` case. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `??` operator understands that if the rhs is not optional, then the result is not optional:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier)
    ?? UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
cell.textLabel?.text = ...  // No ! needed
```

Better yet, if you register your cell identifiers (either in a storyboard or with the `registerNib` / `registerClass` methods), then you can use the newer form of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` which does not return an optional:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("repo", forIndexPath: indexPath)
cell.textLabel?.text = ...  // No ! needed
```

Comment: Of course! I now remember reading about this in the documentation. A perfect use for it.

Answer (score 2):

Let me paste someting copied directly from the UITableView public API:

```
    public func dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier: String, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
// newer dequeue method guarantees a cell is returned and resized properly, assuming identifier is registered
```

Looking at the method above, it guarantees returning a correct cell, thus the return type is not optional and **you can avoid force unwrapping.**

Answer (score -1):

You can also code like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(reuseIdentifier)! 
    cell.textLabel?.text = ...
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = ...
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = ...
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = ...
    return cell
}
```